# Could not push to github using IntellijIDEA

Tags: git, github, push

I have a private repository on github. Added all keys to folders, configured git etc. I have no problems to clone it, pull or push using windows console. But I have some problems, when Im trying to use git with IntellijIDEA. With IDEA I can pull(!) repository and create commits. But I cannot push my commits to github repository using IntellijIDEA.

I have an error:

```
git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I am without any problems can pull repository - IDEA asks me for passphrase for my key and after normally pulls all changes. But it cant push my changes back.

Thanks for help.